# Configuración de Nginx como proxy inverso de Jenkins

Tags: nginx, jenkins

Estoy intentando configurar un Nginx para que actúe como *reverse proxy* de un servicio Jenkins, ambos ejecutados en sendos contenedoroes Docker.

La visibilidad entre los contenedores y *el mundo exterior* es correcta. Desde fuera, puedo acceder a la página de *login* de jenkins mediante la URL esperada

> http://FQDN:8080/jenkins/

Esa URL muestra correctamente la página de Jenkins. Sin embargo, al introducir las credenciales, la página no responde.

Con las herramientas para desarrolladores del navegador, puedo observar lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Todas las peticiones se dirigen a la URL esperada ... **excepto una**, que omite el puerto (marcada en verde). Casualmente, es un `GET /jenkins/credentials/`, por lo que tengo la *ligera* sospecha de que es relevante para el proceso de *login*.

Para la configuración de `nginx`, seguí las instrucciones (adaptadas) de la propia página del Jenkins ([Jenkins behind an NGinX reverse proxy](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+behind+an+NGinX+reverse+proxy)), junto a alguna que otra *cosilla* que encontré por ahí. Al final, el archivo de configuración quedó así:

```
server {
  listen       80;
  server_name  localhost;

  location / {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
  }

  error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;

  location = /50x.html {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
  }

  location ^~ /jenkins/ {
    # IP del contenedor Docker en el que corre Jenkins
    proxy_pass   http://172.18.0.4:8080/jenkins/;

    # Fix the "It appears that your reverse proxy set up is broken"
    proxy_redirect http//MISUPERSERVERIP.es $scheme://MISUPERSERVERIP.es:8080;

    sendfile off;
    proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
    proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;

    client_max_body_size 10m;
    client_body_buffer_size 128k;

    proxy_connect_timeout 90;
    proxy_send_timeout 90;
    proxy_read_timeout 90;

    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_request_buffering off;
    proxy_buffering off;
  }
}
```

También seguí las instrucciones pertinentes al crear el contenedor de Jenkins, usando

> docker create -e JENKINS_OPTS='--prefix=/jenkins' ...

Y, desde dentro del contenedor, si hago

> $>env
>   ...
>   JENKINS_OPTS=--prefix=/jenkins
>   ...

La opción aparece correctamente establecida.

¿ Como configuro correctamente NGinx/Jenkins para que el primero actúe como *proxy* inverso hacia el segundo ?

Comment: Esto me llama la atención `listen 80;` En ninguna parte del código veo 8080.

Comment: @ArtEze está en `proxy_redirect http://MISUPERSERVERIP.es $scheme://MISUPERSERVERIP.es:8080;`. Las llamadas al 80 se redireccionan al 8080

Comment: Encontré esta imagen en la documentación del plugin credentials. Aparece la opción `Hostname:port`... Quizás hay que configurar eso. https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jenkinsci/credentials-plugin/master/docs/images/defining-specification.png

Comment: @ArtEze Gracias. Hay un *problemilla* ... como no puedo hacer *login*, no puedo entrar en esa sección xD intentaré acceder de otra forma.

Answer (score 1):

La primera petición con causa *document* intenta cargar la página. Si te fijas hay una redirección (HTTP 302) y es la segunda petición la que realmente carga los datos.

Pero luego las llamadas AJAX de la página ya cargada se siguen haciendo a la dirección antigua. No sé si están siendo redirigidas (creo que en este caso es algo transparente para el desarrollador y también se redirigen, pero no estoy seguro al 100%).

Así que lo que pasa es que el código Javascript no "se entera" de que ha sido cargado con otro dominio y está llamando siempre a algún valor "harcoded". Pero *en teoría* esta no es la razón por la que el login no te funciona, si te fijas todas las llamadas obtienen un HTTP 200 (OK).

Comment: Ahora, solo falta un detalle de *na*, sin importancia ... ¿¿ Como *carajo* lo arreglo ?? Si lo mio es programar, no pelearme con estas cosas ...

Comment: Tampoco se de que me extraño ... el Jenkins ese está hecho en Java ...

Comment: Tendría que ver qué es lo que realmente te falla, las peticiones parecen correctas